# Does an underground tank need a heater?

Tags: fish, freshwater, heaters

I have dug out a 3ftx3ftx44ft (d/w/h) (0.9mx0.9mx13m) area for raising tilapia, and I will be adding a layer of 6mm plastic to hold the water. I want to know whether I will need to buy a heater for this and if a cover at night would help keep the fish warm. I am worried about this especially because this winter is supposed to be really bad, so I want to invest in a heater now if it will be needed. Tilapia need to be in temperatures 55°F (12°C) or higher, so that is what I am aiming for at the minimum.

[image: Fish hole]

I assume I will need a heater, but I would like to hear from others before I buy one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: IF you need a heater, then you should first add some insulation so your heat will not disappear in the ground...

Comment: I forgot to mention, we have cardboard around the plastic between it and the dirt.

Comment: I do not know, how cold a bad winter is where you live, but here in Lithuania or in Germany it would not help to have cardboard ^^

Comment: @Allerleirauh According to the Farmer's Almanac, we will be having one of the worst winters we have had in 50 years, with a possibility of snow. In Florida, that is unheard of.

Comment: The commercial Tilipia farm here in zone 8 , East TX ,empties outside ponds in winter.  They have a metal building with inside ponds for winter.

Comment: Heat loss is basically from the open surface.

Comment: is the measurments of your pond correct,1m x 1m x 13m ? i have a garden pond that is about 13 x 9 x 1,7 meters l/w/d and i have a hard time understanding how your pond must look.

Comment: @trondhansen It is less of a pond and more of a rectangular hole in the ground. I am using it as a temporary tank until I finish my full pond, which is roughly 7 feet deep and a typical pond shape.

Comment: A photo might be helpful if its not too much trouble

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It is currently late at night where I live, but I will edit my question with an image tomorrow!

Comment: @blacksmith37 if the surface is really this small and the "walls" are much bigger, then no, the loss will happen at the walls and the bottom. Also air is much more insulating than soil or stone :)

Comment: Ponds for koi are sometimes heated, so you can find general information about heating by searching for koi ponds

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I have provided an image, and clarified the state of the tank/pond currently. It is not finished and I have not laid down the cardboard or plastic yet because I would like to ask others how I should proceed. I have done this with plastic and cardboard in other holes, but none of them are used to hold fish, only water plants.

Comment: Where are you in Florida and what Tilapia species are you looking at? I would say you could be safe depending on the year and if you are using permitted fish which are more cold tolerant Blue and Nile Tilapia. But, it would be a good idea to have a pond heater available in case you actually do get a winter that is going to really cool everything down. But, in that sort of pond setup, you will have a ton of temperature losses and you will have a heck of a time as soon as a heron shows up...

Comment: Heat loss from a pond or pool  is primarily caused by evaporation   and radiation. Loss into the ground is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Blue Tilapia (Oreochromis aureus) are the hardiest species - able to withstand water temperatures as low as 46°F. Niles can withstand colder water too but will not breed at temperatures below ~68°F.

In any case, you're better off safe than sorry. An inexpensive failsafe would be to bury some heat cabling below the pond. It will still run cold in the winter, but you'll at least be sure the temp doesn't drop to fatal levels.

Comment: Please add a source for your facts about the fish. If not for proove quality, then for researching further